# Why does imageresizer not work for img tags and only for direct url's?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

I've just added imageresizer to my MVC4 app, but for an image tag as below, it does no resizing. If I paste the url directly into my browser, it gets resized.

```
<img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg?width=130">
```

Why is this? I suspect routing is messing imageresizer around, but I installed the routing shim as instructed. The diagnostic url, /resizer.debug.ashx, only warns me I have NoCache set.

Comment: that looks correct, have you got the correct  handlers registered in your web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the same HTTP request occurs both ways (except for the Referer header, which is irrelevant here), it's impossible for your statement to be true.

One of the following must be happening:

1. Your 'store-display-image' css class contains client-size width/height settings that are overriding the true size of the image.
2. Neither image is being resized (perhaps you're running IIS6 or IIS7 Classic - see the docs for supporting that), but your browser is automatically resizing the 'address bar' version to fit inside the window.
3. Your page has a 'base' tag that is changing the 'src' value.
4. You're just making a typo somewhere.

To avoid downvotes on future questions, I suggest providing more detailed information, such as the exact URL you used in the address bar, the css for 'store-display-image', the document URL containing the img tag, your server details, and a copy of your diagnostics page.

I also suggest showing effort to simplify the circumstances, such as trying an empty HTML page and simple  element with no CSS applied, and (for strange situations like this), screenshots of both situations.

Comment: On 2), the browser is not sizing the image, it measures to the exact size I specify it be resized to. On 3) I have no 'base' tags.

I didn't include all of the detail because I felt it would be superfluous; my question accurately describes the problem. I will update my question with as much detail as possible though, later today.

Comment: Correct, there was in fact a width set in css somewhere.